# Send JSON to webapi controller

Tags: c#-4.0, json.net, dotnet-httpclient

This seems like it should be easy. I need to POST data like this to a webapi controller:

> {
>       "startRace":"2016-08-22T12:00:00.000Z",
>       "endRace":"2016-08-26T12:00:00.000Z" }

So I created a console app and here is the snippet of code that handles the POST event:

```
        var i = (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
        var startRace = DateTime.Today.AddDays(i);
        var endRace = DateTime.Today.AddDays(i + 4);


    var raceDates = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"startRace", startRace.ToString("u")},
                    {"endRace", endRace.ToString("u")}
                };

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(raceDates);

        using (var http = new HttpClient())
        {
            try {

                 HttpResponseMessage response = http.PostAsync("http://localhost:15312/api/race/dates/post",
                   new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

        }
```

But everytime I run the app, I always get this error message:

> String is not in JSON format

Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: I dont think so you need to Serialize object before passing to StringContent. Try `new StringContent(raceDates, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")`

Comment: @Paresh That throws a cannot convert from Dictionary to string...

Answer (score 1):

This is a working example code.

### Console App

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var i = (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
            var startRace = DateTime.Today.AddDays(i);
            var endRace = DateTime.Today.AddDays(i + 4);


            var raceDates = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"startRace", startRace.ToString("u")},
                    {"endRace", endRace.ToString("u")}
                };

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(raceDates);

            using (var http = new HttpClient())
            {
                try
                {

                    HttpResponseMessage response = http.PostAsync("http://localhost:15312/api/race/dates/post/?raceDates=" + raceDates,
                      new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Web API

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{

    public class RaceController : ApiController
    {

        [Route("api/race/dates/post")]
        public void Post(Dictionary<string, string> raceDates)
        {
            var dates = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                 {"startRace", raceDates["startRace"]},
                 {"endRace", raceDates["endRace"]}
            };

        }
    }
}
```